# Do I need to do anything to release the allocated memory in these cases?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Example 1:

```
char* var1 = "Random string";
```

Example 2:

```
char* firstline;
fscanf(input, "%s", firstline);
```

Example 3:

```
char* names[] = {"Karla", "Rob", "Tom"};
```

Comment: On what operating system (if any, or you writing your own one?) and processor??. **With what compiler** and compilation options? Try [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` etc. Notice that `fscanf` can fail. Beware of undefined behavior.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question. This is *not* one

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: How do you think the operating system and compiler matter?

Comment: Because `tinycc` don't generate the same code as GCC or [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) or [CompCert](https://compcert.org/). And maybe Luca is coding an operating system kernel (like [Linux](https://kernel.org/)....).....

Comment: And Luca might have his own C compiler clearing every automatic variable (even if [n1570](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) don't require so, it does permit that)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: None of that has to do with releasing memory. The C standard specifies the lifetimes of these objects.

Comment: I see no memory allocation in the question. In C it would use `malloc` or `calloc`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Reserving memory for objects is called “allocation.” The C standard specifies that memory is reserved by definitions of identifiers for objects. The C standard does use “allocated” to name a type of storage duration, more specifically called “dynamically allocated,” but it also uses “allocated” in the more general sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no dynamically allocated memory in the examples you show.

> `char* var1 = "Random string";`

The memory for `var1` is allocated either statically (for the duration of the program) or automatically (for the duration of execution of its associated block), depending on where this declaration appears. In either case, it is managed by the C implementation, and you do not need to do anything to release it.

The memory for `"Random string"` is allocated statically.

> ```
> char* firstline;
> fscanf(input, "%s", firstline);
> ```

As above, the memory for `firstline` is allocated either statically or automatically. However, `firstline` must be set to point to memory before passing it to `fscanf`. Your example does not show this. If `firstline` is set to memory allocated dynamically, as with `malloc`, then good practice is often to call `free` to release the memory when it is no longer needed. (This is not necessary when exiting a program in a general-purpose multi-user operating system.)

> ```
> char* names[] = {"Karla", "Rob", "Tom"};
> ```

This the same as the first example.

Comment: Thank you so much! As far as the second example (the one where `fscanf` appears), `firstline` is not set to point to memory because while reading a website I once saw that there wasn't such a thing so I assumed it wasn't necessary. Anyway, now I know, thanks again!